# sqlalchemy regexp_match ignore capitalization

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to match this statement

```
stmt = session.query(models.Production).filter(models.Production.profile_name.regexp_match('some_name'))
results = session.execute(stmt).all()
print(results)
```

In `profile_name` column, it's saved as `Some_Name`. How do I get it to match ignoring capitalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer

```
from sqlalchemy import func

stmt = session.query(models.Production).filter(func.lower(models.Production.profile_name).regexp_match(func.lower('some_name')))
```